# Vuetify button custom css color not working

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

According to the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons) the color attribute of a button can be set to a css hex value:

> Applies specified color to the control - it can be the name of
>   material color (for example success or purple) or css color (#033 or
>   rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5))

However, the following adds a class `#3b5998` but doesn't style it:

```
<v-btn color="#3b5998">Should be blue</v-btn>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your vuetify version to `^1.2.0` and it should work.
[Release notes](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v1.2.0):

> Support for custom colors when using the color prop — color="#FFFFFF"

Of course be aware of other changes that update will introduce to your app.

Comment: Yep, that works. Damn I love working with techniques developing this fast!